# How to let R recognize a vector of arguments in the ellipsis?

Tags: r, function, plot, arguments, ellipsis

I'm trying to work smartly with the ellipsis (`...`) argument in R and have some problems.

I am trying to pass some default arguments at the beginning of the function without cluttering up the argument area of the function by using `...` and overriding if they are provided there. But somehow the ellipsis argument doesn't seem to pick up my full vector

```
test <- function(dat, 
                 # I don't want to have to put default col, 
                 # ylim, ylab, lty arguments etc. here
                 ...) {
  # but here, to be overruled if hasArg finds it
  color <- "red"
  if(hasArg(col)) {  # tried it with both "col" and col
    message(paste("I have col:", col))
    color <- col
  }
  plot(dat, col = color)
}
```

Function call:

```
test(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20), col = c("purple", "green", "blue"))
```

Throws the error:

```
Error in paste("I have col:", col) (from #8) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

So something is going wrong here. If I pass the ellipsis arguments to the plot function immediately it does work without error.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be reading [some Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). Search for `dots` on the page I linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this, by **collecting/packing `...` into a list**, if you want to use its contents inside the function.

```
test <- function(dat, 
                 # I don't want to have to put default col, 
                 # ylim, ylab, lty arguments etc. here
                 ...) {
  opt <- list(...)
  color <- "red"
  if(!is.null(opt$col)) {  # tried it with both "col" and col
    message(paste("I have col:", opt$col))
    color <- opt$col
  }
  plot(dat, col = color)
}

test(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20), col = c("purple", "green", "blue"))
```

The problem in your original code, is that `args()` or `hasArg()` only works for **formal arguments** in function call. So when you pass in `col = c("purple", "green", "blue")`, `hasArg()` knows there is a formal argument `col`, but **does not evaluate it**. Therefore, inside the function, there is no actual `col` variable to be found (you can use a debugger to verify this). Interestingly, there is a function `col()` from R `base` package, so this function is passed to `paste`. As a result, you get an error message when trying to concatenate a character string and a "closure".